# $L^2$ vs $L^{\infty}$ norm for interpolation

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, interpolation, spline

Under what circumstances should I consider utilizing the $L^2$ norm instead of $L^{\infty}$ when interpolating a function based on sample points?

Probably related: Does the answer significantly differ depending on the class of approximation functions (polynomials, splines, etc.) I use?

While I know the underlying function to be differentiable, the only sample point data I have is $x$ and $f(x)$, i.e. no values of the derivative for any given point.

(Sorry if this is a bit open, I will try to narrow down the question based on your responses.)

Comment: It all depends on what kind of phenomena you're trying to figure out. If you know your sample data comes from an $n$ times differentiable function, maybe you want some variant of $L^{\infty}$ that involves derivatives. If your sampled data isn't smooth but you're doing some sort of frequency analysis, you probably want to work with $L^2$ since $L^2$ works nicely with Fourier theory (norms are easy to relate). Of course then there's the issue of what kind of interpolator you're using.

Comment: The underlying function is differentiable, however I do not have any derivative sample point data, just $f(x)$ and $x$.